# Under what conditions will SendMessageTimeout(...,SMTO_NORMAL,...) ignore the timeout parameter when sending to another process?

Tags: windows, winapi

Reading the documentation for [`SendMessageTimeout`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644952(v=vs.85).aspx) I thought the only time `SendMessageTimeout` would ignore the timeout parameter was when either:

1. The target window belongs to the same thread
2. Or "If the window receiving the message belongs to the same queue as the current thread[...]"

But I've encountered a case where either I'm misunderstanding what MSDN means by "same queue" or something else is going on.

When MSDN writes same queue, I'm thinking they're referring to the issues related to using [`AttachThreadInput`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681956(v=vs.85).aspx), which I know from reading [The Old New Thing](https://web.archive.org/web/20090223180357/http://blogs.msdn.com:80/oldnewthing/archive/2008/08/01/8795860.aspx) is potentially dangerous.

I've tried my best at producing a minimal example, that hopefully still reflects the actual case I've encountered. *I'm not looking for specific workarounds as I already have lots of options for avoiding this exact issue*.

In short process A periodically broadcasts a message to all windows. Process B monitors process A and at some point decides to politely ask it to close. Process B uses SendMessageTimeout to allow for the case where process A has unsaved changes and puts up a dialog in its `WM_CLOSE` handler.

I've tested this on Win8.1 and Win10. Compiled using MSVC2015 Update 2 and 3, but I don't think anything is MSVC/MSVC version/C(++) specific.

Compile and run: `cl /nologo /W4 /EHsc a.cpp user32.lib && cl /nologo /W4 /EHsc b.cpp user32.lib && a.exe && b.exe`

This should bring up a "Waiting" dialog in process A. I was expecting process B to display an error dialog saying `SendMessageTimeout` failed, but it doesn't. It hangs until the dialog is closed in process A.

```cpp
// a.cpp
#include <windows.h>

#define CLASS_NAME TEXT("A_WINDOW_CLASS")

LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hwnd, UINT uiMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    static UINT uCommonMsg = RegisterWindowMessage(TEXT("CommonMsg"));
    const int nTimerId = 100;
    DWORD_PTR dwResult;
    switch (uiMsg) {
        case WM_CREATE:
            return SetTimer(hwnd, nTimerId, 1000, nullptr);
        case WM_DESTROY:
            KillTimer(hwnd, nTimerId);
            PostQuitMessage(0);
            break;
        case WM_TIMER:
            SendMessageTimeout(HWND_BROADCAST, uCommonMsg, 0, 0, SMTO_NORMAL, 1000, &dwResult);
            return 0;
        case WM_CLOSE:
            MessageBox(hwnd, TEXT("Waiting..."), CLASS_NAME, MB_OK);
            break;
    }

    return DefWindowProc(hwnd, uiMsg, wParam, lParam);
}

int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hinst, HINSTANCE, LPSTR, int)
{
    WNDCLASS wc = { 0 };
    wc.lpfnWndProc = WndProc;
    wc.hInstance = hinst;
    wc.hCursor = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);
    wc.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH)(COLOR_WINDOW + 1);
    wc.lpszClassName = CLASS_NAME;

    if (!RegisterClass(&wc)) return GetLastError();

    HWND hwnd = CreateWindow(CLASS_NAME, CLASS_NAME, WS_VISIBLE|WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW, CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT, nullptr, nullptr, hinst, 0);
    if (!hwnd) return GetLastError();

    MSG msg;
    while (GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0)) {
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessage(&msg);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

```cpp
// b.cpp
#include <windows.h>

HWND hwndAWindow;
int nReceived;

LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hwnd, UINT uiMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam) {
    static UINT uCommonMsg = RegisterWindowMessage(TEXT("CommonMsg"));

    if (uiMsg == uCommonMsg) {
        ++nReceived;
        return 0;
    }

    DWORD_PTR dwResult;
    switch (uiMsg) {
        case WM_CREATE: return uCommonMsg != 0;
        case WM_DESTROY: PostQuitMessage(0); break;
        case WM_USER:
            // Ask window A to close
            if (!SendMessageTimeout(hwndAWindow, WM_CLOSE, 0, 0, SMTO_NORMAL, 5000, &dwResult)) {
                MessageBox(hwnd, TEXT("SendMessageTimeout failed"), TEXT("Error"), MB_ICONERROR|MB_OK);
            }
            SendMessage(hwnd, WM_CLOSE, 0, 0); // We're done
            return 0;
    }

    return DefWindowProc(hwnd, uiMsg, wParam, lParam);
}

#define CLASS_NAME TEXT("B_WINDOW_CLASS")

int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hinst, HINSTANCE, LPSTR, int) {
    hwndAWindow = FindWindow(TEXT("A_WINDOW_CLASS"), nullptr);
    if (!hwndAWindow) return -1;

    WNDCLASS wc = { 0 };
    wc.lpfnWndProc = WndProc;
    wc.hInstance = hinst;
    wc.hCursor = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);
    wc.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH)(COLOR_WINDOW + 1);
    wc.lpszClassName = CLASS_NAME;

    if (!RegisterClass(&wc)) return GetLastError();

    HWND hwnd = CreateWindow(CLASS_NAME, CLASS_NAME, WS_VISIBLE|WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW, CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT, nullptr, nullptr, hinst, 0);
    if (!hwnd) return GetLastError();

    MSG msg;
    while (GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0)) {
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessage(&msg);

        // Once we're sure A is up and running ask window B to do its thing
        if (nReceived) {
            PostMessage(hwnd, WM_USER, 0, 0);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You probably want

```
if (!SendMessageTimeout(hwndAWindow, WM_CLOSE, 0, 0, SMTO_NORMAL | SMTO_ABORTIFHUNG, 5000, &dwResult))
```

in b.cpp.

Also, `WM_CLOSE` can't be sent - it can [only be posted.](https://web.archive.org/web/20061214233824/http://blogs.msdn.com/oldnewthing/archive/2005/02/22/378018.aspx)  Sending `WM_CLOSE` cross-thread often ends up with an `RPC_E_CANTCALLOUT_ININPUTSYNCCALL` error.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but I can't see where the linked post says that `WM_CLOSE` *can't* be sent, only a comment where Mr. Chen says it's "normally posted"? I even found this, admittedly old [KB article](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/178893) that discusses using SendMessageTimeout to post a `WM_CLOSE` message to another application. Also adding SMTO_ABORTIFHUNG doesn't change anything (on my maching at least), which is as expected as process A isn't hung.

Comment: It's *way* down in the comments ([link here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20050222-00/?p=36393#comment-257363)).

Comment: That's the comment I'm referring to, but as far as I can tell it's only applicable to applications using [COM](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/198996), which is not the case here. If the call to SendMessageTimeout from process B failed that'd be fine, but the problem is it's hung forever(?).